# von Neumann stability analysis for spatial variable flux

Tags: stability, fourier-analysis

Can we use the von Neumann stability analysis to investigate the stability of the discrete form of the following problem?

$$u_t+\frac{\partial(x^2u)}{\partial x}=S(u,x)\ .$$

Please give some hint how to use this analysis in the above problem.

Comment: Is the function $S(u, x)$ linear on $u$?

Comment: @nicoguaro yes $S(u,x)$ is linear on u

Comment: You can follow [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis#Illustration_of_the_method) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @nicoguaro I know very well when a is constant. But my question is when flux  function is of the above type

Comment: @Sandy you'll want to look at the so-called method of "frozen coefficients". this [older scicomp post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/method-of-frozen-coefficients-and-its-relation-to-von-neumann-stability-analysis) is a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure there is a rigorous justification, but consider that stability is defined (should be defined) in the following way. That the numerical solution remains bounded as the mesh sizes in time and space tend to zero. So stability is about what happens on fine meshes. On fine meshes, nonlinear problems such as the one you offer "look more linear".

There are other methods of defining stability in the nonlinear case such as energy stability. As far as I know, the outcome is always consistent with von Neumann stability.

Comment: How is this problem nonlinear? OP said the forcing term is linear in $u$.

Comment: @GoHokies What is the question? Flux is nonlinear

Comment: @PhilipRoe no. the flux function is **linear in $u$**.

Comment: @PhilipRoe ... hence this is just a linear advection PDE with a non-constant advection coefficient ($u_t + a(x)u_x = \bar{S}(u,t)$ with $a := x^2$ and linear $\bar{S} := S - 2xu$) .

Comment: @GoHokies The non-constant advection is *precisely* what makes it nonlinear. What you call the method of frozen coefficients is what I would call a local linearization. AFIK, there is no rigorous mathematical justification for this, but it work with amazing reliability. The reason for this is that the CFL is not a mathematical condition but a physical condition, stating that the numerical domain of dependence must include the analytical domain of dependence. This is a local condition. It is clearly necessary but maybe not sufficient.

Comment: I am aware of the significance of the CFL condition. What I'm taking issue with is your definition of "nonlinearity". Anyway, the OP has probably moved on from this problem, so let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule to re-write your original PDE as a inhomogeneous advection equation with variable advection speed:

$$u_t + x^2 u_x = S(u,x) - 2 x u.$$

Then use the method of *frozen coefficients* to investigate stability of the corresponding discrete PDE problem (taking into account, of course, any boundary and initial conditions you may have). Check out [this older scicomp post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/method-of-frozen-coefficients-and-its-relation-to-von-neumann-stability-analysis). Here's a couple more references to get you started:

http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~restrepo/475B/Notes/sourcehtml/node37.html

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~ascher/520/chapt05.pdf

Comment: what will be the  CFL condition in the  above problem if  we modify the above equation as u suggested.

Comment: @Sandy you ignore the RHS (as that is irrelevant when considering discrete stability), and apply the method of "frozen coefficients" for the discrete left-hand side, as shown on pages 3-4 of the slides i linked to.